# Broadcasting UDP message from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to send a broadcast message from a C# app on one machine to a Python script on another. If I specify the Python machine's IP as my endpoint, I can send a message just fine. Here's how I'm sending my message:

```
const int PORT = 12345;
using (var sock = new UdpClient())
{
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIP), PORT);
    //var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, PORT);

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello, world!");
    sock.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, endpoint);
}
```

On the Python side, I'm receiving as follows:

```
import socket
PORT = 12345

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', PORT))
#sock.bind(('<broadcast>', PORT))

while 1:
    data,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    if not data: break
    print(data)
```

I can send my message from one machine to another successfully. However, I have multiple machines to which I want my message to go (UDP broadcast), but when I use `IPAddress.Broadcast` as my endpoint, Python doesn't receive my message. I've also tried binding my Python socket to `<broadcast>`, but that doesn't help, and binding to my C# machine's IP gives me the error `socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`.

I don't know if this is an issue of C# not sending the broadcast or of Python not receiving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a network analyzer such as Wireshark to verify the operation of your networking code. I suspect that if you do, you will find that no broadcast datagram is actually set.

Lacking [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say for sure what the reason would be. But the cause of this would most likely be because you have not set the [`Socket.EnableBroadcast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.enablebroadcast(v=vs.110).aspx) property for your socket. It defaults to `false` and if not set to `true`, broadcast datagrams won't be sent even if you send to a broadcast address.

Comment: The code turned out to be valid with one exception: the broadcast address I was using routed the packet to my Windows Phone network device emulator. Wireshark did helped me track down this issue. I found that a point-to-point message worked correctly because it was getting routed to my virtual switch; broadcast, OTOH, got dropped by the WP emulator. I manually set my broadcast equal to the one's-complement of the subnet ORed with the target machines' IP addresses.

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted because Wireshark did ultimately get me to the answer. Thanks!